Selecting degrees of freedom in stepwise regression (stepAIC function in R)
Context: I have data available on water quality in a number of catchments, for example the concentration of Zinc (Zn). For each catchment, I also have a range of characteristics (n=16), such as the average elevation and slope, or the proportion of different land cover types (e.g., urban, agricultural).
There are lots of methods available to select which of these characteristics are most important in explaining the variability in water quality, such as expert opinion / theory, partial least squares regression, LASSO, elastic net methods, ridge regression and stepwise regression. While there are many disadvantages to using stepwise, this is the method I am currently using [note: this analysis is not for research but for teaching purposes, giving opportunity for critical engagement].
To use stepwise in R, I would first construct a linear model:
# Fits a linear model, including all other columns (~.) as independent variables
zn_model <- lm(formula = Zn ~ ., data = model_df)

To perform stepwise regression, we could use step() from the stats package or stepAIC() from the MASS package, here using the latter:
# Stepwise model
step.model <- stepAIC(zn_model, direction = "both", 
                      trace = FALSE, k = 2)

From the documentation, k equals

the multiple of the number of degrees of freedom used for the penalty. Only k = 2 gives the genuine AIC

This returns the following output:
Coefficients:
                       Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)            30.80991   24.60874   1.252 0.217845    
average_elevation       0.09583    0.03540   2.707 0.009926 ** 
average_rainfall       -0.07308    0.01876  -3.895 0.000364 ***
average_aspect         -0.06559    0.04378  -1.498 0.141969    
Arable_percent          0.35771    0.22094   1.619 0.113297    
Heath_percent           0.69317    0.28778   2.409 0.020706 *  
Grassland_percent       0.48670    0.21753   2.237 0.030897 *  
Urban_percent           0.96455    0.22102   4.364 8.74e-05 ***
Wetland_percent         0.52525    0.25851   2.032 0.048844 *  
Sands_and_Muds_percent -0.10270    0.05353  -1.919 0.062181 . 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 9.583 on 41 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.6017,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.524 
F-statistic: 7.744 on 8 and 41 DF,  p-value: 2.881e-06

For the purposes of the teaching exercise, I would like to produce more parsimonious models, removing less important variables, in this case, the average_aspect and arable_percent, and potentially others.
This could be achieved by increasing the degrees of freedom used for the penalty, for example:
# Stepwise model
step.model <- stepAIC(zn_model, direction = "both", 
                      trace = FALSE, k = 4)

This produces the following:
Coefficients:
                  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)       37.28031    9.70645   3.841 0.000374 ***
average_elevation  0.09429    0.02667   3.536 0.000940 ***
average_rainfall  -0.05416    0.01581  -3.426 0.001299 ** 
Urban_percent      0.51266    0.09382   5.464 1.82e-06 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 10.09 on 46 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.5051,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.4728 
F-statistic: 15.65 on 3 and 46 DF,  p-value: 3.751e-07

This is a much simpler model (only 3 independent variables), for a relatively small reduction in R2 (0.6 -> 0.5). There is, however, no clear rationale for choosing a specific value of k, only increasing incrementally until all are deemed "significant" (in the example above, all are p < 0.05).
Other answers on Cross Validated suggest that the value of k can be changed, such as here, but most other examples use either the AIC (k = 2) or BIC (k = log(n)).
Question: Ignoring for now the broader issues with stepwise, is it legitimate to change the value of k from the standard AIC or BIC values? If so, is increasing k incrementally to produce the desired model parsimony also an acceptable approach?

You are just using k as a tuning parameter. By that, you appear to want to justify only selecting variables with coefficients where p < 0.5. That is not legitimate.

I'd be very careful in demonstrating something like this for 'didactic' purposes. With $n=41$ and $p=16$ characteristics, this is a textbook example of what not to do.

@Roland Thanks. Can you expand your comment into an answer, explaining why it is not legitimate, so I can accept this as a response?

Thanks for the advice @FransRodenburg. The number of samples is limited by practical considerations i.e., data collection is costly, requiring time and equipment. To shift to a textbook example of "what to do", would the solutions be to (1) collect more data for a better ratio of $n$ to $p$ and/or (2) reduce the number of independent variables, or is there an alternative method that might be more suitable for a dataset with this characteristics?

If further data collection is not an option, I would do these things in order: 1) Determine which, if any variables are of lesser importance to the research question and omit those unless they are expected to lead to substantial omitted-variable bias. 2) Remove any obviously colinear variables (e.g., you have multiple percentages of types of land, you cannot have them sum to $100%$). 3) Reduce the number of variables with sparse PCA (importantly, without using the outcome). 4) Fit a regularized model that does not do selection (e.g, ridge regression).

@FransRodenburg Thanks!
